Short animated short film about a man at the gates of heaven explaining his life using figurative speech
I think it is a Merrie Melodies animation, it does not feature any know well know characters, it is western animation, in color and from the 1950-1970.
The story is about a guy who dies and tell his life to Saint Peter at the gates of heaven. The trick is he uses figures of speech and Saint Peter takes it literally. 

Sounds like the Tex Avery cartoon Symphony in Slang from 1951. From Wiki:

A young man (a real swinging hep cat) goes to Heaven and steps before St. Peter. But his life story is so peppered with slang that neither St. Peter nor Noah Webster can understand him. What follows is a series of sight gags based on Webster's literal interpretations of the slang terms, such as his first job being helping out a proprietor who is 'short handed', but being 'unable to cut the mustard', he is 'given the gate'.

You can see the first 3 minutes here:




Ha!  I almost asked this same question a few weeks back, but found it by googling a few of the terms I remembered.  It's a classic.

BTW, at the moment, the only full-length version I know of is on Vimeo: http://vimeo.com/100989067
